# Glosan and soapy taste

Tags: kegerator

Cleaned lines with Glosan (followed directions and flushed with a keg of purified water) and now there is a soapy taste to the beer. Anybody else have this happen? suggestions for how to avoid this are welcome for an alternate cleaner for the lines. Thinking of just switching to Oxyclean, but wonder if that will really clean the gunk in the lines without soaking.

Comment: Glosan is made by WESMAR company out of WA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you've found a cleaner that I've never heard of before. Glo-san, from the one online seller that sells it, it claimed to be like PBW.  But I can't find any real MSDS for the product nor any real discussion on it.

I would suggest you throw the Glo-san away.  Too sketchy.

I would suggest [BLC Beer Line Cleaner](http://www.nationalchemicals.com/store/template/product_detail.php?IID=56&SID=bb019de2c5f51faba3bf3b6989ff7829). BLC requires a 15 minute soak and then a rinse.  There really isn't going to be a cleaner that doesn't require a soak. If there is beer stone present, it requires a soak.  We use BLC, it works great no residual taste.  You just have to mix properly and rinse.

As to Oxyclean, it's good stuff for a lot of tasks, but is slow to dissolve deposits. The BLC is pretty cheap and basically comes to a few cents per application and is designed for the task at hand.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! Was thinking of going to a commercial beer line cleaner, so this confirms the thought :-). I'll look up the PBW. As a chemist, I also tried to look up the active ingredient's MSDS, I'm REALLY sensitive to what goes into anything that I serve for consumption, and couldn't find any references in my resources. Again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem Nice thing about BLC and other products from National Chemical is that they have MSDS right on their site, easy to get.  Good luck!